# kali rolling install on External HDD problem

Tags: kali-linux, shutdown, external-hdd

I encountered some problems after installing kalil inux to the external hard drive. 
I installed kali linux to a mobile hard drive.(Mobile hard drive is USB conversion SATA HDD ) 
Hard disk partition is GPT boot mode UEFI ，Connect the hard disk to the USB port with a connector
 **Kali updated to the latest**

- system：kali rolling X64
- Computer is laptop
- external HDD :TOSHIBA 5400 500G 7mm (Laptop dedicated hard drive)
- USB to SATA :UGREEN us221 (converter)

#### The problem

Every time the system is shut down, the hard disk has an abnormal    sound. It is like the sound of WINDOWS system forced shutdown. This    sound is working properly in the computer, manually holding down the    power button for more than 5 seconds.   So I judge that the hard disk    is not working properly when the computer is turned off.

- Ubantu had similar problems but it has been fixed.[About Ubantu
  problem Link](https://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?f=86&t=76016) Following similar solutions in kali were invalid.

  #### Steps to reproduce

  1. Use USB to SATA mobile hard disk to fully install Kali GRUB installed in hard drive
  2. Boot into UEFI mode
  3. After the startup is complete, click Shutdown Button
  4. The last moment after the shutdown is completed, the hard disk will be abnormally bad.//This process is to ensure that the problem can be repeated//

At last
**I hope that the hard disk can enter the standby mode when the system is shut down.Reduce the sudden loss of power to damage the hard disk And data loss**

[image: Photograph of setup]

Comment: Do I understand correctly?:  Did you have the same problem on Ubuntu and managed to fix it?  If so can you add information on exactly what you tried?

Comment: @PhilipCouling Have you managed to understand the question at all?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes. Ignore the Chinese Paragraphs, it just repeats the English.  The simple version is that the USB HD powers down hard on shutdown.  Elsewhere... windows appears to spin down gently.  The question mentions a fix for ubuntu but it's not clear if this has actually succeeded for the OP on Ubuntu, or if they have simply found a suggestion and tried / failed to apply in in Kali.

Comment: @sinaAdonis I've tried to clean up the translation. If I got this wrong you can [edit] again to fix.

Comment: @PhilipCouling  thanks everyone,  My English is bad , so translate from googel. about Ubantu This link chinese   https://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?f=86&t=76016